# Wrong sign in integration by substitution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Consider the following integral:

$$I:=\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 (x-y)^2 \,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy = \frac{1}{6}\tag{1} \quad .$$

Suppose that we want to solve it via integration by substitution and thus define $w(x,y):=x$ and $z(x,y):=x-y$. The absolute value of the Jacobi-determinant equals one and so I think that $I$ can be rewritten as

$$I=\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_w^{w-1} z^2 \,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dw \tag{2} \quad .$$

However, we then obtain $I=-\frac{1}{6}$. Obviously the negative sign comes from the integration limits of the $z$-integration, i.e. the sign error can be fixed by swapping the limits. But is there a reason why we should swap the limits (because I think that from a simple calculations this order is correct)? Where is the mistake?

Comment: The Jacobian is -1.

Comment: How did you get the limits?

Comment: @BobDobbs In any case we're considering the *absolute value* of the Jacobian, cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)

Comment: Negative Jacobian changed the orientation.

Comment: @BobDobbs Yes, I see now with the help of the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide if you are doing signed integration or not. If you are doing signed integration, you don't take the absolute value of the Jacobian, just like you wouldn't in one dimension where signed integration is customary. If you decide to use unsigned integration like in the link you provided, your substitution changes the domain from $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ to
$$\{(w,z) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : w \in [0,1], z \in [w-1,w]\}.$$
Thus, by Fubini, we get
$$I = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_{w-1}^w z^2 \,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dw$$
and all is fine again.

Comment: Thank you very much. So for a signed integration the domain would be $z\in[w,w-1]$ (although this seems strange, but anyway this would be just notation with that I mean that it runs from $w$ to $w-1$)? One more thing: You mentioned Fubini - for what exactly this is needed here, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jakob Yes, it is just notation that comes out of the substitution rule if you do it that way. You technically need Fubini to convert the integral over a two-dimensional domain into a double integral.

Comment: I see. Thanks again very much for your help, much appreciated. I actually just found a part in *Calculus. G. Strang*, p. 532, where this 'sign issue' is mentioned, too.